# Fullscreen API in webkit browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, fullscreen

I am working on a toggle for the JavaScript Fullscreen API. Somehow the **exit fullscreen mode** (the else statement) in Webkit Browser doesn't work. Can someone hint what is wrong? The code is the example code of the Mozilla Documentation of the fullscreen API.
  var toggleFullScreen;

```
toggleFullScreen = function() {
  if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullScreenElement)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
      return document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      return document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      return document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else {
      return console.log("didnt happen");
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      console.log("Mozilla Proposal cancels Fullscreen");
      return document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      console.log("Firefox closes");
      return document.mozCancelFullScreen();

// This is the line:

    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      console.log("Webkit closes");
      return document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else {
      return console.log("Can't close");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: for "webkit browser" you mean chrome or the buggy safari?

Comment: There's several [jQuery plugins](https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin) that helps to simplify fullscreen, might be worth checking into.

Comment: both safari and chrome. I don't look for a plugin, since the native code is easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript ... This is the page I use when Im referencing fullscreen oriented code... it should help.

Comment: That link does not work any longer. DNS probe cannot find it. Has it possibly been moved?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent article that describes how to do this. It's from 2012, but it seems to work.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Takeaways from the article:

```js
function enterFullscreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen({ navigationUI: "hide" });
    }
    else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen({ navigationUI: "hide" });
    }
    else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
        docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

function exitFullscreen(){
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }
    else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
    else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
}

function setOnFullscreenChange(callback){
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
        callback();
    }, false);
    
    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
        callback();
    }, false);
    
    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
        callback();
    }, false);
    
    document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
        callback();
    }, false);
}
```

Note that modern versions of firefox do not require the `moz` prefix.

Also (not from article) to check if fullscreen is enabled

```js
function getIsFullscreenEnabled(){
    return document.fullscreenEnabled 
    || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled;
} // checks if the browser supports fullscreen

function getIsBrowserInFullscreen(){
    return document.fullscreenElement != null 
    || document.webkitFullscreenElement != null;
} //checks if browser is currently in fullscreen mode. Note that document.fullscreen is deprecated
```